# .menu() is not a function; jQuery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration, upgrade

I am migrating a menu widget from jQuery 1.6.4 to a newer version of jQuery , 1.11.1

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#takeMeToLink').menu({
                content: $('#globalContent1').html(),
                flyOut: false
            });
        });
```

Markup

```
    <a id="takeMeToLink" href="#" style="color:black">
        Take Me To
       <span style="height:3px;width:15px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;" class="s4-clust ms-viewselector-arrow">
       <img src="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png" alt="Open Menu" style="border-width:0px;position:absolute;left:-0px !important;top:-491px !important;" /></span>
    </a>
```

When I replace the .js file with the new one, it throws an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).menu is not a function
```

Is there a new function available?

Comment: I think menu is in jquery ui, which is a separate script that you will need.

Comment: Does the widget say it supports the newer version of jQuery? It might also help if you could specify which widget your are using and what version.

Comment: The menu() function is nowhere to be found in the jQuery documentation, nor the jQueryUI documentation. None to be found in the "Deprecated since 1.x" section on either websites either. Nothing on Google.

Comment: @D.Visser https://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.menu() is a Jquery UI "widget", which means you need to include JQuery ui.

Here's the script and stylesheet on google's CDN that you should include as well as your JQuery script(feel free to download it if that's easier):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the documentation: https://jqueryui.com/menu/

Here's an example of how to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/FwBNE/1/